# Unable to build Xcode project in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, visionos

I wrote an app for visionOS and I decided I want to add iOS and iPadOS support for the app. I added iPad and iPhone for supported destinations, but when I try to build it via the iPhone or iPad simulator, I get error:

> Building for 'iphonesimulator', but realitytool only supports [xros, xrsimulator]

Nothing in my code is specific to visionOS and I can't see anything mentioning realitytool. I've tried messing around with build architecture settings, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you got any assets that may depend on realitytools ?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when trying to port a visionOS-only app to iPhone and iPad. This is because you need to modify the build phases of your target so that it only loads RealityKitContent when on visionOS, not on iOS. Here's how to fix it:

1. Click on the root of your project in the project navigator.
2. Go to your target.
3. Go to the "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content".
4. On the "RealityKitContent" row, click on the filters icon next to "Always Used", uncheck "All Platforms" and check only "visionOS".

[image: See the screenshot for reference.]

Next, you'll likely have different build errors, like "No such module 'RealityKitContent'". To fix this, you'll want to replace the import statement from

```
import RealityKitContent
```

to

```
#if os(visionOS)
import RealityKitContent
#endif
```

Comment: Not working for me, and also getting 'None of the input catalogs contained a matching stickers icon set or app icon set named  "AppIcon"' even when there's an AppIcon

Comment: I had the same issue. It's because the visionOS AppIcon asset is different than the iOS AppIcon one. Go to Assets > + > iOS > iOS App Icon. That fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you @benb. You are right, adding the iOS App Icon solves this particular issue, but unfortunately still complaining about the RealityKit even after following your steps. Only creating a separate target worked for me by now.

Answer (score 0):

@benb suggestion makes totally sense, but it seems there're are still some bugs here. According to [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/736991), this block:

```
import SwiftUI
#if os(visionOS)
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent
#endif
```

May be incorrectly parsed, and apparently adding an extra line break might help:

```
import SwiftUI

#if os(visionOS)
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent
#endif
```

But even with the extra line break, I needed to create a separate target for `iOS` (the `#if` directive is still needed, though).