# Is it possible to create an iOS and visionOS compatible app within a single project?

Tags: ios, swiftui, visionos

I've been working on several `visionOS` demos without concerning about multiplatform compatibility, now than I'm ready to develop a full app I've found out that creating a multiplatform project (at least `iOS` and `visionOS`) isn't as straight forward as I expected, now not even sure if it's possible.

Choosing `Multiplatform` in the new project wizard only allows running on `iOS` and `macOS`, and choosing `visionOS` only allows (obviously) running on the visor. I understand that Apple Vision has unique capabilities, but for an app that it's 90% a regular SwiftUI windows navigable, I'd like to think that I don't need to mantain to parallel projects.

**So is it possible to have one single project executable in all devices? (even if there're some specific immersive features available only for visionOS)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can even have your project compatible to macOS. When you setup your Xcode project, you must add the `Apple Vision` and `Mac` app `Designed for iPad`.

The Apple's idea is to create an iPad version of your application, which is compatible for those two devices. You still have to use conditional statements to use different background materials for your visionOS app or other setup, but it is easy to do so with SwiftUI.

Xcode Version 15.2

To do so, within your Xcode project, go to: Your project Name -> Your Project Target -> General -> Supported Destinations.

If you want to have the full Apple Vision app with their material background, select `Apple Vision` as the destination in place of the one `Designed for iPad`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @RolandLariotte, exactly what I was looking for. Now I'm dealing with some errors as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77945003/unable-to-build-xcode-project-in-ios-simulator, but it's a great starting point :)

Comment: Why does the Mac app have to be the "Designed for iPad" version? With SwiftUI you can just as easily choose the native Mac destination. Though the whole "you can even have your project compatible with macOS" part of the answer seems to just be extra info unrelated to having an iOS app and visionOS app in one project.